# Cinematic renders / scattering / foliage

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, workflow, performance

I'm looking for advice on how i can use some high quality assets and scatter them fairly densely in a scene,

I feel as if I've seen certain workflows in max and other industry software where as you are able to create some really attractive and dense foliage renders without heaps of performance loss or crashing.

one of my problems is I find myself trying to reduce the poly count of a lot of my assets and this is unfortnantly reducing the overall quality of the render in trying to do so.

Any links or help would be hugely appreciated! :)